# Angular Material custom theme makes popups transparent

Tags: angular, sass, datepicker, angular-material2

I'm currently working on a dashboard in Angular with Material2 for styling.  I'm having a problem where any popup in the app to appears with a transparent background.

I have make an example of the problem in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agxab6).

In the stackblitz the problem appeared when i added a  [custom material theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

When i remove the `"src/theme.scss"`  from the projects `angular.json` file and use a prebuilt material theme in `style.css` like so;

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

The popup's backgroud is normal again.

This happens to all popups (datepicker, paginator, etc.).

My `~/src/theme.scss` file looks like this;

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// always include only once per project

@include mat-core();

// define 3 theme color
// mat-palette accepts $palette-name, main, lighter and darker variants
$dashboard-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$dashboard-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-grey);
$dashboard-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// create theme (use mat-dark-theme for themes with dark backgrounds)
$dashboard-theme: mat-light-theme(
    $dashboard-theme-primary,
    $dashboard-theme-accent,
    $dashboard-theme-warn
);

$dashboard-theme-dark: mat-dark-theme(
    $dashboard-theme-primary,
    $dashboard-theme-accent,
    $dashboard-theme-warn
);

.dashboard-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dashboard-theme);
}

.dashboard-theme-dark {
  @include angular-material-theme($dashboard-theme-dark);
}
```

The theme is applied to the project on a `<div>` in `app.component.html`

Any help is much appreciated :)

## UPDATE

I have updated the entire project to use `scss` instead of `css`, then I rebuilt my entire custom `theme.scss` All material components get styled properly, I can dynamically switch between light and dark theme, I can even style non-material components. But my popups stay transparent unless I use a prebuilt theme as described above.

I also updated all dependencies just to be sure;

`package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "DiagnosisDashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.8",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.10.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.4.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

`angular.json` :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/app/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/app/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

New [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfjr4k).

Comment: You have your base palette defined somewhere? mat-palette expects your mat-blue, mat-gray etc to have a color map somewhere acting as your base palette. Looking at your stackblitz though something seems off since I don't see a background-color ever applied and there's some strange overrides I wouldn't expect to see when expecting the output. Do you get any warnings or anything on compile of the sass?

Comment: Hello @ChrisW., No i haven't defined my own palette. I was under the impression that Material provided some default palettes just like they provide default themes. I did not read anything on needing to define one myself in the documentation (https://material.angular.io/guide/theming). Where would i place the definition of this palette? in a sass file?

Comment: I do not get any compile errors btw.

Comment: Might go skim over a step-by-step [tutorial](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.html) and make sure you're not missing anything.

Comment: @ChrisW. I just redid the entire theme, now using sass in the entire project instead of css and sass mixed. theme gets applied normally, i can switch between dark/light theme, i can style custom components but the popups are still transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Popups" are contained in the overlay container which is the immediate child of `<body>`. Any styling applied to your base app component will not be applied to the overlay container - you have to apply it explicitly. See the "Multiple themes and overlay-based components" section of the [theming docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes). For example:

```
import {OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

export class AppComponent {

    constructor(overlayContainer: OverlayContainer) { }

    applyTheme(theme: string) {
        this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, i did not see that in the documentation, fixed the problem instantly. +1